# Getting values from cells in table using class. Jquery

Tags: jquery, class, html-table, cell

How can I get values from cells in table using class?
Col2, Col3, Col4 have common class "punkty". In Col5 I want set result of addition from Col2,Col3,Col4. In my recent solve, I'm getting string values from row, example "13230", by I would getting 13 and 23 and 0, then input value 36 to Col5.

```
$("#tab tr").each(function (idx) {
  var ar = $(this).find('.punkty').text();
  alert(ar);
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qxLL6/7/)

Anybody can help me? :)

Comment: Can you post some code, and to solve your string value issue, you need to convert them to integers before performing the addition.

Comment: Ok, but I have a problem with getting value from each cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wj5Ra/)

You can use the `text` attributes function to calculate the sum from siblings and set its own text.

```
 $('#tab tr .suma').text(function(){
   var sum = 0; 
    $(this).siblings('.punkty').each(function(){ //Iterate through the siblings to calculate the sum.
     sum += +$(this).text();
    })
 return (sum==0 ? '-' : sum) ; //return '-' if no sum.
});
```

Comment: Note:- if `punkty` has non numeric values this will give sum as NAN. You would need to add additional validation if required.